# How to use field value on form and then use in pre-operation plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I am creating one plugin which will run on pre-operation and it will need a date which is still on the form ( user filled it ). I need that date and use in the plugin. How can achieve that. As this is pre-operation plugin and values are not yet saved in dataverse

Comment: When the form is not saved no plugin step is triggered on the server side. Please, explain what do you need to achieve.

Comment: I want to fetch a date which is on the form and then need that date in plugin to calculate something based on that date in plugin

Comment: Even pre-operation plugins require the user to save the record

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

1- Get entity from Plugin :

```
Entity entity = pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
```

2- Then Get Date:

```
DateTime? dateTime = null;
if ((entity.Attributes.ContainsKey("new_userdate") && entity.Attributes["new_userdate"] != null))
    dateTime = entity.Attributes["new_userdate"];
```